# weird results on db_dump(berkeley db)

Tags: dump, berkeley-db

I have about 400MB sized berkeley db file.

```
$> ls -alh ses.db
-rw-rw-r-- 1 junyoung junyoung 391M  9월 23 17:32 ses.db
```

after dumping it, I've checked the size again.

```
$> db_dump ses.db > ses.db.dump
$> ls -alh ses.db.dump
-rw-rw-r-- 1 junyoung junyoung 2.2M  9월 23 18:09 ses.db.dump1
```

the result file size is too small than I expected.
what's the reason of this? any comments?

Answer (score 0):

There could be many reasons for this, to be sure.  But possibly the most common reason is that the database once held many more records which were later deleted.  This space is not returned to the filesystem.

See this thread in the Oracle forums for more information https://community.oracle.com/thread/879030 .  And, as it says in there, try the db_stat command to get some visibility into what's going on in your database.